# Remove duplicated entries mysql

Tags: mysql

So, I have a small table that has some duplicated entries that I want to delete. 
There are two situation:

```
 1  2
+--+-+
|A |1|
|B |1|
|A |2|
|C |1|
+--+-+
```

This table is absolutely correct even if there is a duplicated record in first column. 
And it it the `bad` result that I want to avoid.

```
 1  2
+--+-+
|A |1|
|B |3|
|A |1|
|C |2|
+--+-+
```

As you can see, there are two `A` with value `1` that is duplicated entire and I want to remove it. 
And the correct table would be like that

```
  1  2
+--+-+
|A |1|->remain
|B |3|
|A |1|->delete
|C |2|
+--+-+
```

So is there any proper way that allows me to do it via mysql? Or should I write a script on %language_name% to do this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a unique index to your table:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE MyTable
ADD UNIQUE INDEX idx_name (col1,col2);
```

where `MyTable` is the name of your table, `col1` and `col2` the names of yourcolumns `1` and `2`.

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f176ba/2

Comment: Nice solution. Why didn't I remember it?